# Exclude Div in updatepanel Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

Asp.Net 4.5 (WebForms)

How can I exclude the container div from async postback? The container is rendering webgl. I tried adding it to the Triggers as suggested on other searches but I get an error.

**Error**

- Control with ID 'container' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl...

**Note**

- If I move the container outside of the updatepanel then it works, however the location would be wrong then.

**Example**

```
 <div id="main" class="main">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div>
                    <div>
                       more controls ...
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="container" class="container" runat="server"></div>

                <div>   
                     more controls ...
                </div>

              </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
               <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="container" />
           </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use 2 separate update panels for *div*s above and below the *container* div?

Comment: @vnikhil Good question. This happens to be nested within other updatepanels. I just left all that mess out of the example. Otherwise I would definitely use 2 separate updatepanels.

Comment: I think you're finding one of the limitations of UpdatePanel. Perhaps it would be better to abandon UpdatePanel and instead go with coding AJAX calls (perhaps using a helper library such as jQuery) to your server side? The result is often easier to understand and debug, and results in less bandwidth use and less server load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For short term solution I separated out all the updatepanels to flow around the div removing it from the Async postback which did indeed work. This was suggested by vnikhil.

For long term solution I would consider mason's suggestion from the posted comments.